# Best way to implement module system in PHP MVC App?

Tags: php, oop

Im currently developing my own PHP MVC Framework.
This application is for personal purpose, and may be release open source a day.
I am implementing a modules system in the application.
For example, the Core will run, and a user installs a "Artist" module (composed with a Entity, a Model, and a Controller)
The user will have the ability to update the template.
So at a moment, he will be writing for example :
$this->app()->getModule('Artist')->getAll();

If for some reasons, the administrator disable the "Artist" module, frontend will display :

```
Call to a member function getProperty() on null
```

And the script will stop.
Is there any ways to silent this error ?
I know about magic calls, but I don't know how to cascade it, that the

```
$this->app()->getModule(string)
```

will stop and return for example "Module desactivated", instead of trying to reach inexistent entity and model.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think a good and clear way is just to check if the module is there. You may check for a null value, like so:

```
$artistModule = $this->app()->getModule('Artist');
if ($artistModule)
  $artists = $artistModule->getAll();
```

But another pattern that may be useful in some cases are NULL objects. That is actually a replacement object with an empty implementation. So for a module, it could implement basic methods like get(), getCount() and getAll() (or other methods that you have), and return default values, like 0 for the count and an empty array for getAll.

So, the module loaded would replace the artist module with a NullModule, and upon calling `$this->getModule('artist')->getAll()`, you would just get an empty array instead of the list of artists.

```
$artists = $this->app()->getModule('Artist')->getAll() ;
```

Still, it would be a good idea if the module had any way to explicitly check whether it is active, so a programmer could at least check it if needed. Such a function, say `getActive()` can just return `false` in the NullModule, so the first snippet could be rewritten as:

```
$artistModule = $this->app()->getModule('Artist');
// $artistModule will be a NullModule instance if Artist is disabled.
if ($artistModule->isActive())
  $artists = $artistModule->getAll();
```

The advantage of Null Objects, is that you only have to check for the module being active in a couple of places, while more generic code doesn't need to check anything. It can just function as it would with a 'real' module.

But that can be a disadvantage too. If you didn't check properly, your code can seem to run as normal, while actually it shouldn't run at all.

See [Null Object pattern on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: Oh, Okay, many thanks !
I'll use the solution of having a small check before trying to go further.
As I don't know how many functions are requested (example : getModule('Artist')->getFirst()->getFullName(), or getModule('Song')->getTopFive()), this will be the most simple solution. Thanks !